# Could someone point me to a context menu in a listview

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I'm trying to add a feature to my app. and that is a menu (context menu/option menu) for every item in the listview. However, I'm having problems finding a tutorial or article on how to do this. The menu would be similar to this one on the picture.
http://pctechtips.org/pics/android_listview_menu.png. I'm not going to post any code since. Here's the github for the app.
https://github.com/zentech/Netdroid

I just want someone to point me where to get started with this
Thanks

Comment: The pic link is broken. Please fix it. Would help those, who are referring to this question in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to show pop up menu on Click of the 3dots image inside the adapter

***Code:***

```
//Creating the instance of PopupMenu
            final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(activity, level);
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_level, popup.getMenu());

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    level.setText(item.getTitle());
                    return true;
                }
            });

menuImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {          

            popup.show();//showing popup menu
        }
    });
```

[tutorial here](http://rajeshandroiddeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-popupwindow-example-in-listview.html)

Comment: how can I get the three dots to show? do I need to create a menu.xml file with <items> and then load it in the adapter? or just an image with three dots will do it?

Comment: "\u22EE" use this unicode and set it to textview and set onClick on textView and things should work

Comment: you can use image if you wish . you wont get it for free like action bar

Comment: TextView.setText(unicode)... will give 3 vertical dots